Are there any "interesting" algebras where "$1 \cdot 1 = 2$"?
This equation is not a typo; I really do mean multiplication, not addition. This question is inspired by how that there was some recent online controversy involving the TV actor Terrence Howard, who pushed a "kooky" - and admittedly, so jumbled in some places I'd suggest it "not even wrong" - treatise centered around the idea that $1 \cdot 1$ should not actually be equal to 1, as one is usually taught, but instead should be equal to 2. And while as I said Howard's treatise seems to be rather incoherent and full of errors, one point he does make that is sensible at least by itself is that the equation $1 \cdot 1 = 1$ arises from the identity axiom for a ring or field: viz.

Given a ring $R$, there exists a $1 \in R$ such that for any element $a$ of that ring, including $1$ itself, $1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$.

And Howard says that this is essentially just asserting to be true that $1 \cdot 1 = 1$, which he then doesn't like for other reasons. I.e. that from a purely logical point of view, this is an arbitrary axiom - and thus perhaps we could explore alternatives. And I have to say that trying to see if I could wring some sort of legitimate and sensible maths out of this has been a bit of a pastime for me lately too and that brought me to this.
You see, people questioning and challenging him, naturally, asked him also "well if $1 \cdot 1 = 2$, then what is, say, $1 \cdot 2$?" And he said the answer was 3, and in general, that (in summary) $1 \cdot a = a + 1$. And this makes me wonder. Suppose we take the usual axioms for a ring at least (i.e. not a field), and we replace the identity axiom with the following modification:

Given a "Howard pseudo-ring" $H$, there exists a $u \in H$ such that for any $a \in H$, $u \cdot a = a \cdot u = a + u$.

(Note that a "Howard pseudo-ring" is just the name, for lack of any better, that I would give to this class of hypothetical structures - so all other defining axioms are just the remaining ring axioms.)
What can be said about such "Howard pseudo-rings"? Are there any interesting and non-trivial examples?
Note that one system that seems like it might meet this "$1 \cdot 1 = 2$" requirement would be the so-called "tropical geometry", in which $\cdot$ is given by the usual addition, and $+$ is given now by a min or max operation, together with the adducement of a suitable "infinity" point which then comes to serve as additive identity. That does generate a fair bit of interesting math, however that system is not a ring(-like) structure but a semi-ring(-like) structure only, in that additive inverses do not, in general, exist. Thus, what I want to know is if any true ring-like structures, i.e. with additive inverses, that meet the above property, exist - and if so, what are they? In particular, are there any that can be considered as defined on the usual real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ viewed as an ordered set at least, and that are compatible with the order in the usual ways, including that both operations are continuous functions? And if not, why not?

ADD: Changed to a different symbol for the modified $1$-element so that we can work with this alongside the usual numbers with less confusion; c.f. Martin Brandenburg's comment.

$1 = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 + 1 = 2$ implies that $1 = 0$, no? Then the ring/algebra/etc. is trivial.

@GeorgeCoote no. the ring is not unital - they removed the identity axiom

oh I see, overlooked that @LucasHenrique

Please give that element a different symbol. It will be much less confusing to work with these structures then. For example, $$ux=xu=x+u$$looks already better.

@MartinBrandenburg: done.

Suppose that we're given an abelian group (or a weaker hypothesis - a cancellative monoid) $R$ with a (left or right) distributive operation $\odot: R\times R \to R$ and such $1 \in R$; let $0$ be the additive identity. Clearly $0=0+0$, so $$1\odot 0 = 0 + 1 = 1$$ and $$1 \odot (0+0) = 1\odot 0 + 1\odot 0 = 1 + 1.$$ So $1+1 = 1 = 1+0$ and using the cancellative property, $1 = 0$. Now, for any $a \in R$, we have$$a\odot 0 = 0\odot a= a+0 = a.$$
Which implies that $$a+0 = a\odot 0 = a\odot (0+0) = a\odot 0 + a\odot 0 = a + a.$$ Using the cancellative property again, we have that $a = 0$; i.e. $R = \{0\}$. So there aren't nontrivial structures with this property.

Thanks! That would explain why the tropical geometry is possible, then - the failure to exist of additive inverses is crucial for that system's viability.

In a non-unital ring $R$ with an element $u$ such that the equation $ux = x+u$ holds for all $x$, apply this to $x=0$ to get $u=0$. The equation becomes $0=x$ for all $x$, so $R$ is just the zero ring. It's not an interesting concept.
